# Парсер html сравнить или проверить, остановку динамического времени

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть html на нём две колонки: мак адрес и дата-время. Мак адрес постоянная величина, дата-время динамическая, меняется каждую секунду. Мак адрес и дата-время беру парсером через xpath. Xpath возвращает мне вот такого вида строку: ['СССС600E9334']['25.10.2017 16:18:57']
Как сделать так, что бы при остановке времени, выводился принт: Не работает.
Вопрос заключается, как или сравнить или проверить, что врем остановилось.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

a = 'hostname '

response = requests.get('URL')

parsed_body = html.fromstring(response.text)

now = datetime.now() + timedelta()
now1 = now.strftime("['%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S']")

b = (str(parsed_body.xpath('//*[@id="nameBody"]/tr[449]/td[1]/text()'))) #xpath mac-address
c = (str(parsed_body.xpath('//*[@id="nameBody"]/tr[449]/td[2]/text()'))) #xpath date-time 
print(a + b + c)
```

Comment: А что мешает просто проверять полученную строку с той что приходила секунду назад? Я же правильно понимаю, что строки будут поступать, а меняться будет только время\дата? А если время\дата не изменились - то и строка будет такая же как и предыдущая. Значит время остановилось и дальше не продолжать работу

Comment: @Vladimir Novopashin
Строка не меняется, меняется только время, если обновлять html страницу или перезапускать скрипт. В том то и дело что нем могу реализовать, не знаю как сделать, если есть какой нибудь пример, буду признателен.

Comment: xpath возвращает **список**.  Чтобы строку с датой достать, используйте индексацию [0], уберите str()

Comment: @jfs так проблем с доставанием даты и времени нет, str там для того что бы это всё сложить в принте `print(a + b + c)`

Comment: вызов str() не нужен, чтобы напечатать a,b,c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы узнать прошло ли больше минуты с указанного времени в цикле:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime 

timeout = 60 # seconds
while True:
    time_string = '25.10.2017 16:18:57' # XXX get the time (xpath(..)[0])
    then = datetime.strptime(time_string, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S') # parse it
    now = datetime.utcnow()  # XXX use appropriate time zone here
    elapsed = (now - then).total_seconds()
    if elapsed > timeout:
        print("stopped")
        break
    time.sleep(timeout - elapsed)
```

Comment: @sakhalin прочитайте под вопросом мой комментарий о том что xpath() возвращает. Откуда вы код в вопросе взяли, если вы не знаете как из `L = ['abc']` списка достать строку `'abc'`? Что по вашему `L[0]` вернёт?

Comment: я разобрался что str не обязателен и сделал теперь так `c = parsed_body.xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[93]/td[2]/text()')
print(a, b, c)`

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался, понял, всё работает, обновил код в шапке. Но работает при условии если time_string = равняется одной переменной, например time_string = c1 или с, так всё работает, а как сделать массовую проверку пока не знаю...

Comment: @sakhalin: "шапка" называется *вопросом* на этом сайте. Не помещайте код с решением в вопрос (если нашли решение, можете опубликовать его как свой ответ -- [это явно приветствуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)). Если у вас возникла новая проблема, то задайте новый вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
time_last = (str(parsed_body.xpath('//*[@id="nameBody"]/tr[449]/td[2]/text()')))
time_lim = 0
while True:
    response = requests.get('URL')
    parsed_body = html.fromstring(response.text)
    time_now = (str(parsed_body.xpath('//*[@id="nameBody"]/tr[449]/td[2]/text()')))
    if time_now == time_last:
        if time_lim == 0: time_lim = time.time()
        if time.time() - time_lim >= float(60): #проверяем что с момента превой остановки времени прошло 60 секунд
            print("Time stoped") 
            time_lim = 0
    else time_last = time_now
```

Comment: Скрип не отрабатывает к сожалению...

Comment: @sakhalin что именно происходит? Он вообще никогда не печатает "Time stoped", или печатает, но не тогда когда правильно?

Comment: Я тогда поправлю ваш пример, что бы нагляднее было, сюда почему то не могу код вставить, точнее не форматируется.
В общем, при каждом запуске, скрипт пишет постоянно Time stoped

Comment: @sakhalin попробуйте теперь

Comment: @sakhalin я добавил эту строку `parsed_body = html.fromstring(response.text)` без нее он постоянно парсил одно и тоже не получая новые данные с сайта

Comment: Эх нет =)) не работает, тоже самое пишет, всегда Time stoped и зацикливается но это не проблема break ему в помощь. Но не работает, на html странице время меняется и перезапуском скрипта тоже видно что меняется, т.е. время идёт,  а скрип пишет Time stoped.

Comment: @sakhalin попробуйте еще с этой строкой `response = requests.get('URL')`

Comment: Спасибо, уже что то похожее на правду, но похоже работать не будет, точнее будет, но не правильно. Т.к. на самой страничке html время может подвисать на 10 сек или на 1 мин, т.е. 1 минуту может не обновляться время, а через минуту будет опять обновлять. Скрип начинает писать Time stoped, но это не правда получается.
Пока не могу понять как реализовать такой метод адекватной проверки....

Comment: @sakhalin можно попробовать ввести проверку и выводить  "Time stoped"  только тогда, когда оно стоит уже больше минуты. Я добавил ее в скрипт, посмотрите, сработает ли

Comment: Спасибо, работает, но очень сложно получается. Плюс, если time_last действительно остановился, скрипт начинает отсчитывать 60 сек и только тогда пишет Time stoped и так еще через 60 сек и еще раз через 60 сек. Но не в этом проблема. У меня таких переменных будет много которые нужно будет проверять....

Comment: @sakhalin, логично, а как вам такое решение – записывать в массив 10 раз время, проверять равны ли все элементы в массиве и если равны выводить что время остановилось? Но так придется проверять для каждой переменной, что не очень оптимизировано. Но другого решения я не вижу.

Comment: Честно скажу не знаю, придётся наверное просто получать все значения через xpath записывать это в переменную и принтом выводить, будет большой список из примерно 30-40 строк на выходе, с временем из html страницы. И глазами уже проверять =)

Comment: @sakhalin попробуйте в вопросе сразу все требования записать. Что может зависать 10..60 секунд, потом снова обновлять время. Как скоро вы хотите узнать (2 минуты это поздно?) Что у вас "таких переменных будет много".  Идеально было бы push уведомления использовать (вы один раз подписываетесь на интересующие вас события, передав ссылку куда обновления посылать. Когда событие произойдёт ваш обработчик вызывается)

Comment: @jfs Я бы вообще хотел что бы скрипт не проверял в течении 60 сек или 2х минут. Я думал что можно как то проверить остановку времени, если время остановилось, выводил бы что то типа: устройство не работает. Если разница с а ласт таймом устройства и реальным времени больше чем на 10 мин. то выводится принт, устройство не работает.... Не знаю на сколько понятно изъясняюсь...

Comment: @Звягинцев Денис Кстати Денис, мысль возникла, а возможно как то, проверить, time_last и time_now если разница между ними в 10 мин, то выводится принт.... как то так. Без проверок в 60 сек

Comment: да, для этого используется `timedelta`

Answer (score 0):

Получилось в конечном итоге вот так:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from datetime import datetime
import time

a = 'HOSTNAME'

response = requests.get('MY_URL') # URL for parsed

parsed_body = html.fromstring(response.text)

b = parsed_body.xpath('//html/body/table/tbody/tr[350]/td[1]/text()')[0] # mac-address
c = parsed_body.xpath('//html/body/table/tbody/tr[350]/td[2]/text()')[0] # datetime

b1 = parsed_body.xpath('//html/body/table/tbody/tr[356]/td[1]/text()')[0] # mac-address
c1 = parsed_body.xpath('//html/body/table/tbody/tr[356]/td[2]/text()')[0] # datetime

timeout = 60 # seconds
while True:
    time_string = c1 # XXX get the time (xpath(..)[0])
    then = datetime.strptime(time_string, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S') # parse it
    now = datetime.now(tz=None)  # XXX use appropriate time zone here
    elapsed = (now - then).total_seconds()
    if elapsed > timeout:
#        print(a, b, c, 'stopped')
        print(a, b1, c1, 'stopped')
        break
    else:
#        print(a, b, c, 'rabotaet')
        print(a, b1, c1, 'working')
        break
    time.sleep(timeout - elapsed)
```

Всё работает, только при условии, что `time_string =` равняется одной переменной, например `time_string = c1`

Comment: это неверно. request.get() итд следует внутрь цикла поместить, иначе `time_string` не меняется.

Comment: @jfs У меня при этом коде, время `time_string` меняется. Даже проверил `print(time_string)` после перезапуска скрипта всегда разное время, соотвествующее времени на странице откуда его беру.

Comment: внутри цикла `time_string` не меняется. Если вас это устраивает , то вообще цикл уберите (правда это никак к вопросу не относится). Чтобы время на самые самые основы не терять, прочтите любую книгу по Питону для людей не знакомых с программированием.